# Data structure for maintaining large sets of alias for fast look up

Tags: data-structures

I have a list (>50,000 words). Each word in the list has a set of associated alias(es). Each word, on an average, has 5 aliases.

I get an input string averaging to 6 words. I have to do:

```
// Pseudocode 
foreach word in input_string
    if word == x  or  word in alias(x) // x is a word in the list
       tag (word, x)  // Tag word with x
    else 
       tag (word, 0)
end
```

What is a fast data structure to maintain a list of alias which will enable fast execution of above look up on it?

Comment: Do you have have any space constraints? If not a simple dictionary/hashmap will give you good lookup performance

Comment: Any comparitive statistics for various data structures on such look ups?

Answer (score 3):

An [associative structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) with O(n/k) or O(log n) lookup would be appropriate.

Examples include:

- [hashtables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table); or
- [tries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)